# Numpy: np_array[index_order_array] changes the order of elements in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to Python and Numpy

Why `array = [1,2,3,4]` and `new_array = array[[3,2,0,1]]` results in changing the order of elements as mentioned in the inner array?

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
array_link = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E'])

new_array = np.ndarray(5, dtype=np.int32)
new_array_link = np.ndarray(5, dtype=np.int32)

perm = np.random.permutation(array.shape[0])

new_array = array[perm]
new_array_link = array_link[perm]

print(new_array)
print(new_array_link)

# Output:
# [30 40 10 50 20]
# ['C' 'D' 'A' 'E' 'B']
```

Here is the [Playground](https://trinket.io/python3/62a09680da)

Is this how it is supposed to work? Shouldn't it be initializing a new (perhaps 2D) array with the elements of inner array (as the first row)?

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to. Everything seems normal to me. What are you expecting?

Comment: You are just creating new arrays that are permutations of the original ones.

Comment: As I have already mentioned in the question I'm wondering why `new_array = array[[3,2,0,1]]` wouldn't initialize a new (perhaps 2D) array with the elements of inner array (as the first row)?

Comment: I think you are confusing `[]` with`()`, the former is for indexing, and the latter is for constructing new arrays.

Comment: Just a note: it's good practice to avoid using the `np.ndarray` class to construct arrays. Use `np.array`, `np.empty`, etc. where possible.

Comment: @Psidom no, here array is identifier referencing a variable, not a function, hence cannot use () on it _unless I import `np.array` as `array`_

Comment: @Psidom, doesn't seem to be so normal, looks more like numpy is doing some magic, [python](https://trinket.io/python3/5e4525ccc1) throws an error

Comment: You need to look into numpy indexing and the difference between python list and numpy array.

Comment: I don't know what it is called, so I don't know where to look into the docs - where inside the numpy array docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first of these 2 lines is useless.  `python` does not require that you initialize or 'pre-define' a variable.  The first creates an array; the second also creates one, and reassigns the variable.  The original value of `new_array` is discarded.

```
new_array = np.ndarray(5, dtype=np.int32)
...
new_array = array[perm]
```

And as a general rule, `np.ndarray` is only used for advanced purposes.  `np.array`, `np.zeros` etc are used to create new arrays.

`array` is a poor choice of variable name. `array` looks too much like `np.array`, and actually confused me when I first copied the above lines.

```
array = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
```

In sum your code does:

```
In [28]: arr = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
In [29]: perm = np.random.permutation(arr.shape[0])
In [30]: perm
Out[30]: array([2, 0, 1, 4, 3])
In [31]: arr1 = arr[perm]
In [32]: arr1
Out[32]: array([30, 10, 20, 50, 40])
```

`arr1` is a new array with values selected from `arr`.  `arr` itself is unchanged.

You could assign values to predefined array this way:

```
In [35]: arr2 = np.zeros(5, int)
In [36]: arr2
Out[36]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
In [37]: arr2[:] = arr[perm]
In [38]: arr2
Out[38]: array([30, 10, 20, 50, 40])
```

In `arr[perm]`, the result is the same shape as `perm`, in this case a 5 element 1d array.  If I turn `perm` into a (5,1) column array, the result is also a (5,1) array:

```
In [40]: arr[perm[:,None]]
Out[40]: 
array([[30],
       [10],
       [20],
       [50],
       [40]])
In [41]: _.shape
Out[41]: (5, 1)
```

Another example of array indexing - with a (2,2) array:

```
In [43]: arr[np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])]
Out[43]: 
array([[10, 20],
       [30, 40]])
```

Comment: thanks, found more on docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays)